# Save data:image to phone Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: file, cordova

I'm using Cordova camera and cordova file plugin.

How can I save the data from a canvas to phone storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use canvas.toDataUrl() method to get the image uri from canvas. More info here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: Yes, thats not the problem. The problem is that data:image to save it asa .png / .jpg image in the phone.